# Как вычисляется разрешение в мобильных браузерах?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript, вёрстка

Почему при разрешении дисплея в 1920x1080 мобильный браузер отображает сайт шириной в 320пх?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что нет мета тега viewport на странице и берется значение по умолчанию

Comment: Есть, с такими параметрами 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
что с viewport, что без него показывает ширину 320пх

Comment: Судя по всему на ретине device-width=320px. Нужно указывать в пикселях.

Comment: Не ретина ведь, full hd пока только.